# Get closing price from a specific bar_index?

Tags: pine-script

Seems like a very silly question, but I can figure out the best way to get this value (just learning).
I'm getting the bar_index from "if ta.crossover". You can do bar_index+1 to get the next bar, is there a way to do close+1 or something similar for the next closing price?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function `ta.barssince()` for that.

```
condition = ta.crossover()

var nextClose = 0.

if ta.barssince(condition) == 1 //one bar after the condition
    nextClose := close
```

Comment: haha bless you, appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take:

```
//@version=5
indicator("Test", overlay = true, precision = 0)
startBarIdx = input.int(0, "Start bar index")
float startBarSourcePrice = na

if bar_index == startBarIdx
    startBarSourcePrice := close[last_bar_index - bar_index]
    label.new(bar_index, startBarSourcePrice, str.tostring(startBarSourcePrice))
```